# Save user profile information _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta6 to write some information to the current ApplicationUser "profile" but the value is null and I don't get any exceptions running the following code.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public TestController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // GET: /<controller>/
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var userObject = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Context.User.GetUserId());

        //This value is null even the second time I hit this breakpoint. 
        var shouldHaveAValue = userObject.MyStringList;
        userObject.MyStringList = new List<string>();
        userObject.MyStringList.Add("testId");
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userObject);

        return View();
     }
}
```

I might be completely wrong here but this is the way I figured it should be done when I saw

```
// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<string> MyStringList { get; set; }
}
```

The example is implemented in the ASP.NET5 web template.

//Edit:
Could it be the way I added the column? I did this since I get errors running the migrations commands which is stated not to be ready on the ef documentation page.( dnx . ef apply )

```
migration.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    MyStringList = table.Column(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
```

Comment: Did you migrate the database? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: @rism Migrations don't work but I added it manually to the startup script creating the database so the table column exists.

Comment: @rism Added info about creation of the table column.

Comment: I don't understand your problem with running migrations? Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh, looking at your mapping, you're trying to map a `nvarchar` field to a list? This wont work. I had assumed this was a navigation property. Think about how EF would try to extract that  field what would the separator be for the individual strings etc? It simply doesn't know how to map it. Either make it a string and split upon materialization or create a separate "Tags" entity and configure the relationship between the two.

Comment: @rism "...problem with running migrations". It is Entity framework 7 in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta6" and migrations is not complete. Could be something that can be fixed but I'm not diving in to that. 1/2

Comment: @rism 2/2 I thought nvarchar(max) would be able to hold a list :) What should I replace it with more exactly? I couldnt find any better in the documentation.

Comment: Ultimately its just a string as far as the db is concerned. You can handle `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, args) =>` in your context, where `args.Entity` contains the entity, to map the string to a list using your own separator logic say `string.Split` and you'll also have to ensure that if you modify the list during the objects lifetime that you also modify the string field that gets mapped back to the db as well.